# Assign rows of similar Time a numerical group value in R

Tags: r, time-series, grouping

I have two groups of similar times with an break between 6:07:45am and 6:15:25am. I want to create an additional column and assign a group value to differentiate the two groups.

Original:

```
Date        Time
12/7/2019   6:06:48
12/7/2019   6:06:52
12/7/2019   6:07:12
12/7/2019   6:07:29
12/7/2019   6:07:31
12/7/2019   6:07:39
12/7/2019   6:07:41
12/7/2019   6:07:45
12/7/2019   6:15:25
12/7/2019   6:18:03
12/7/2019   6:18:05
12/7/2019   6:18:07
12/7/2019   6:18:10
12/7/2019   6:18:22
12/7/2019   6:18:25
12/7/2019   6:19:12
12/7/2019   6:19:16
```

Desired outcome:

```
Date        Time    Group
12/7/2019   6:06:48 1
12/7/2019   6:06:52 1
12/7/2019   6:07:12 1
12/7/2019   6:07:29 1
12/7/2019   6:07:31 1
12/7/2019   6:07:39 1
12/7/2019   6:07:41 1
12/7/2019   6:07:45 1
12/7/2019   6:15:25 2
12/7/2019   6:18:03 2
12/7/2019   6:18:05 2
12/7/2019   6:18:07 2
12/7/2019   6:18:10 2
12/7/2019   6:18:22 2
12/7/2019   6:18:25 2
12/7/2019   6:19:12 2
12/7/2019   6:19:16 2
```

Comment: is there a time threshold for the break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a threshold, then use

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Group = cumsum(c(1, diff(as.ITime(Time)) > 180)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", 
"12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", 
"12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", 
"12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019", "12/7/2019"), Time = c("6:06:48", 
"6:06:52", "6:07:12", "6:07:29", "6:07:31", "6:07:39", "6:07:41", 
"6:07:45", "6:15:25", "6:18:03", "6:18:05", "6:18:07", "6:18:10", 
"6:18:22", "6:18:25", "6:19:12", "6:19:16")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Comment: the threshold is usually around 3 minutes or greater, so your assumption of 180 seconds was spot on! many thanks!